# How Do I Use Google Fit with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fit

Im trying to implement the health package in flutter but I'm finding the code for it a bit difficult to understand as I'm a beginner and can't find any videos on it either.

All I want to do is display the number of steps in my app which will be taken from google fit/apple health, up for any tips on how to do the same.

Thanks.

Comment: The example code of the mentioned health package show you how to fetch step count

Comment: Yeah I know but I can't understand that code can you help me with that or share any video on it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner too and I myself have been struggle to find the solution on how to use the Health package for the past 2-3 month. I may have find the solution, I will try to provide key points and explain them on how I succeed to use the package on Android devices (I have not tested the package on iOS devices).

P/s: This is my first comment ever on GitHub.

STEP 1: Create project on Google Cloud Platform (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started). You are going to need SHA-1 fingerprint and package name from your Flutter project (From my understanding, this is how your apps communicate with Google APIs). Just follow the steps provided until you obtain an OAuth 2.0 client ID.

STEP 2: [Add your Emails on Test Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuLup.png). Enter an email you would like to read data from Fit Apps. You will need Fit apps installed on your device. The email must be the same as the email used in Fit apps. You have to do this step manually because your apps is still in test mode. You are going to need to verify your apps with Google in order to automatically save users email.

STEP 3: We are going to use the code from [this project made by MadsVSChristensen](https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/tree/master/packages/health). We cannot use the whole application from MadsVSChristensen because the SHA-1 fingerprint and package name are different from our own Flutter apps. Therefore, we are only need to copy their codes into our project. You can create new page on your Flutter apps to display MadsVSChristensen project (This is just a dummy and it is okay if you don't understand MadsVSChristensen's code. Our objective is to fetch data from Fit apps into our Flutter apps. After you succeed, you can try to read and understand the whole code).

STEP 4: PERMISSION! As stated in [Health package](https://pub.dev/packages/health), you will need to enable permission for your Flutter apps on the devices. You can try to use permission_handler or you can manually enable the permission on your Android devices.

STEP 5: Test your Flutter project on physical devices. Somehow I can't fetch data from Google Fit apps on emulator devices.

Hope this helps.